# Bash - giving parameter to function via pipeline

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to clean the file from its remarks (#example) and transfering the output to function named func, but it doesnt work. what am I doing wrong? 
it says something is wrong in line 3. "func command not found"

```
#!/bin/bash 

cut -d"#" -f1 $1 | func

function func {
    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to have the `func` definition before you can use it.